# Extract Text with Python from Webpages within div class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to get songtexts from a webpage. Below I have two versions of how I want to achieve that because with the first one I only could get the text from within the first `<p>` paragraph but sometimes within the div class songbook there are several `<p>`. With the second version I achieved that but it includes the whole html. The ".text" only works if there's only one item and not several ones (list).

I'm a bit lost here and also a newbie to Python and BeautifulSoup so I appreciate your help very much.

```
#Extract the songtext only and save it in file
 url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.udo- 
 lindenberg.de/mit_dir_sogar_n_kind.57754.htm')
 content = url.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

 #search on page for div class block songbook and extract songtext between <p>
 table = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"block songbook"})
 for item in table:
     sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')
     songtext = item.find('p').text
     print(item.find('p').text)

#extracts the songtext with html markers
page_link = 'https://www.udo-lindenberg.de/mit_dir_sogar_n_kind.57754.htm'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
textContent = []
for i in range(0,200):
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"block songbook"})
    textContent.append(paragraphs)
    sys.stdout = open('output2.txt','wt')
    print(paragraphs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved it myself. I've found the mistake. The line at second version:

```
paragraphs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"block songbook"})
```

has to be changed to:

```
paragraphs = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"block songbook"}).text
```